# How to write changing variable to text file

Tags: python, file

I'm receiving measurements from laser and web camera. Calculated results are on one variable but I can't write them to a text file when changing. It writes first or last value... I ain't sure. I tried a lot but stuck here, will be very grateful for any help :)

```
theta = 0.0011450 * vzd + 0.0154
tan_theta = math.tan(theta)

if tan_theta > 0:
    vz_obj =  int(5.33 / tan_theta)

    print "\033[12;0H" + "Vzdalenost: " + str(vz_obj) + "cm"

    myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'w')
    myfile.write("%s\n" % vz_obj)

    myfile.close()  

elif rval == 0:
    print " chyba kamery "
```

Comment: `vz_obj` is just an integer (as you can see on line 5), it cannot contain more than one value. It's simply just one measurement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open it with **"a"** parameter which means "append" so it will not overwrite the file but add the value at the end of it.

```
myfile = open('xyz.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: @NevenDary If the answer works for you, the standard procedure to say “thanks, this solved my problem” is to *accept* the answer (click the gray check-mark to make it green).  Read [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more info.